# Dashed border style for table in html to pdf

Tags: asp.net, html, css, itext

I am goggling last 24 hours but not succeeded yet. Basically i have a small problem in ITextSharp:

I need to create dashed border style for table in html to pdf scenario.

Here's my markup:

```
<table style='border-style: dashed; border-width: 2px'>
  <tr>
    <td>content goes here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You didn't tell us if you're using the deprecated HTMLWorker or the new HTML Worker.

Comment: I am getting the same issue in iText with XMLWorker version 5.4.2 for Java. Only outer border appears that too plain border instead of dashed border. Also, the inner borders of table's cells just vanish.  Please help.